# .NET 5.0 preview 7 location of output files automatically adds a folder "net50"

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5

I began migrating all of my visual studio .net projects to the upcoming version of .net to be released next November 2020.

The first thing i noticed was the build path output automatically appends a folder "net50" in visual studio 2019 16.7.

[image]

How can i make the output the one i specify on project properties ? without the added net50 folder.

Comment: Why? This is neither a bug nor a problem, not even a new change. All .NET Core versions work that way. You *need* different folders if you intend to target multiple runtimes which, you will sooner or later. You may be targeting Windows now, but you'll have to target Linux sooner or later, if only to take advantage of cheaper VMs on any cloud providers. Even if you don't target multiple OSs, you'll target multiple runtimes - 3.1 now, 5.0 later, 6.0 one year later. 5.0 isn't an LTS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop visual studio appending the "net50" folder when building a project, one needs to edit the .csproj file and add the following lines

```
<PropertyGroup>            
   <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```